# Euclidean Norm Calculation

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If ||x||$_2$ = 3, ||4x-5y||$_2$ = 14 and ||5x+2y||$_2$ = 8 find ||y||$_2$

I had attempted to write at the vectors in explicit form and in doing so arrived at a point where I would add (||4x-5y||$_2$)$^2$ = (14)$^2$ and (2)(||5x+2y||$_2$)$^2$= 8$^2$(2) to remove <x,y>. From there I would subtract out 66||x||$_2$ by adding on (-66)(||x||$_2$)$^2$ = (-66)(9). Now I get a negative answer of -270/33. Is it possible to get a negative answer? I was under the impression that Euclidean norms acted like absolute value signs. Any advice and explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What space are $x,y$ in?

Comment: It is in the real numbers

Comment: Are you sure? Because the 2-norm of a real number is just the absolute value. Seems kind of silly to write 2-norm in that case.

Comment: I am practicing for a class that covers the study of Real Numbers. I am assuming that it would be the Real Numbers, but I am treating this numbers by the standard definition of Euclidean norm anyway

Comment: My advice to you is to verify that the space is $\mathbb{R}$ (the real numbers) and not $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some natural number $n$. To answer one of your questions though, the $2$-norm cannot be negative.

Comment: It is R$^n$ and I had been unwittingly treating it as such. Is there any reason why I keep getting negative answers? Can I simply negate it and say is 270/33 if its like an absolute value sign?

Comment: You cannot just negate the negative answer. You're getting a negative because you're making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\textbf{x},\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Recall the definition of the Euclidean norm

$$||\textbf{x}||_2:=\sqrt{\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{x}}.$$
So the equations you were given really read

\begin{align*}
||\textbf{x}||_2 &=\sqrt{\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{x}}=3,\\
||4\textbf{x}-5\textbf{y}||_2 &=\sqrt{(4\textbf{x}-5\textbf{y})\cdot (4\textbf{x}-5\textbf{y})}=14,\\
||5\textbf{x}+2\textbf{y}||_2 &=\sqrt{(5\textbf{x}+2\textbf{y})\cdot (5\textbf{x}+2\textbf{y})}=8.
\end{align*}
Squaring both sides to remove the radical gives
\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{x} &=9,\\
(4\textbf{x}-5\textbf{y})\cdot (4\textbf{x}-5\textbf{y})&=196,\\
(5\textbf{x}+2\textbf{y})\cdot (5\textbf{x}+2\textbf{y})&=64.
\end{align*}

Using properties of the dot product, can you solve this system of equations for $\textbf{y}\cdot \textbf{y}$?

Comment: Combining the last 2 equations while first multiplying the bottom equation by 2 I get that, 66x$^2$+33y$^2$=324 . Substituting x$^2$ i get 66*9+33y$^2$=324 and there is my issue. Still confused where my issue is

Comment: I obtain the same thing now that I actually finish the problem (to be honest I didn't really understand your remarks about the steps you took to solve the problem in the OP -- I just looked at the problem). But there are no mistakes here. So either the answer is there is no solution or you miswrote the problem.

Comment: Sadly I have checked the question countless times and it is the right question. I may have to sleep on it

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is that there is no solution as seen by the fact that we get a negative solution which is not possible